# css setting div element to inline block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set two div elements to inline but its not working as expected

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGHZ5/)

html

```
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
```

css

```
#id1{
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline;

    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
#id2{
    background-color:green;
    display:inline;

    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Inline elements dont have height. What is not working as expected?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot specify width/height for inline elements..

Use `inline-block` instead

```
display:inline-block;
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CGHZ5/2/

---

And if indeed you want identical boxes which only differ in color, then use a class for the common properties..

```
<div id="id1" class="item"></div>
<div id="id2" class="item"></div>
```

and

```
.item{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#id1{background-color:blue;}
#id2{background-color:green;}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CGHZ5/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

`inline` elements cannot have defined height or width, they take the height and width of their contents.

Just change all of your `inline` references to `inline-block` like so:

```
#id1{
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
#id2{
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width of a `display:inline` will not work, it just won't display. Use `display:inline-block` instead, although that has some legacy browser issues

Use this code instead

```
#id1{
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
#id2{
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:
```